# Manage Object of unknown Type

Tags: apex, javascript, type

This may sound silly but i am really stuck... I have installed a custom managed package which gives the ability to use plugins and call from Javascript Apex.

JS Code:

```
  //Initialize object to be passed to Apex
      var jsonText = {
        currentCommercial: CS.getAttributeValue("Commercial_Product_0"),
        previousCommercial: CS.getAttributeValue("Old_Commercial_Product_0"),
      };
      // Call Apex class to define whether transition is valid or not
      CS.Service.invokePlugin(
        "ChangePackagePlugin",
        JSON.stringify(jsonText)
      ).then(
        function onSuccess(result) {
          //return CS.setAttributeValue('Attribute1_0', result);
          alert("success... " + result);
        },
        function onFailure(error) {
          alert("Error executing javascript in rule action: " + error);
        }
      );
```

Then an Apex class is called but my problem is i don't know how to parse the input "Parameter". When i do system.debug i see that the parameter is RequestWrap:[currentCommercial=a3L1l0000005b9gEAA, previousCommercial=a3L1l0000005b9gEAA]. However i can't find a way to parse it. I want to get those values, perform some validations and then return a "transitionRulesValidationData" as a response. This plugin call returns a Promise object (did't understand what it really is).

```
global class el_ValidateChangePackage extends csutil.PluginManager.ABasePlugin {
    RequestWrap reqwrap;
    global override Type getParameterType() {
        return RequestWrap.class;
    }
    
    global class RequestWrap {
        public String currentCommercial;
        public String previousCommercial;
    }
    
    public class transitionRulesValidationData{
        public String validationStatus;
        public string validationMessage;
        
        public transitionRulesValidationData() {
            this.validationStatus = validationStatus;
            this.validationMessage = validationMessage;
        }
    }
    
    global override Object invoke (Object parameter) {
        //try {
            reqwrap = parameter; //I get an error on this that Illegal assignment from Object to el_ValidateChangePackage.RequestWrap
        } catch(Exception e){
            validationData.validationStatus = 'EXCEPTION ERROR';
            validationData.validationMessage = e.getMessage();*/
        }
        return reqwrap;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to parse this response and return a "transitionRulesValidationData" response  to the js side?

Comment: What if you simply do: `reqwrap = (RequestWrap) parameter;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I'm making an assumption about the behaviour of this managed package code. However, given the debug output you showed, I believe you likely simply need a cast in your code:

```
    global override Object invoke(Object parameter) {
        try {
            reqwrap = (RequestWrap) parameter;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            validationData.validationStatus = 'EXCEPTION ERROR';
            validationData.validationMessage = e.getMessage();*/
        }

        return reqwrap;
    }
```

Whilst it isn't directly documented, every Apex class (be that an SObject type, a built-in API class, a managed package's visible global class or a class you create in your own Apex code) extends `Object`. This gives you an ultimate base class that you can use in methods where you typically only need to pass the object through, or where (without the benefit of user-code-level generics) you need to treat an object in a very generic way.

Any type of object can always be assigned directly to a parameter or variable of type `Object` since that is simply treating that object as an instance of a class from which it has inherited. However, you always have to explicitly cast down the inheritance hierarchy because not every `Object` is an instance of a given specific Apex class. If you do the cast and the object isn't of that required class you will get a runtime error. If it is of the given class then it will simply allow you to treat the object as that type at that point in the code.

As an aside, with use of classes and methods across namespace/package boundaries, I would suggest that:

1. Your `RequestWrap` class (and, by extension, your `el_ValidateChangePackage` class that contains it) **must** be `global` in order to allow the managed package to create an instance of that class using `Type.newInstance` or `JSON.deserialize`.
2. Your implementations of the required methods from `csutil.PluginManager.ABasePlugin`, such as `getParameterType`, do not need to be `global` and can instead be just `public`. This is the case because the base plugin has already defined this method across the namespace/package boundary (so the package can invoke it) and you can happily override or implement it with a `public` method.

Comment: Phil, thank you so much for the detailed response! :)

Comment: @GiorgosGalaios No problem. BTW, you have some weirdness in your `transitionRulesValidationData` constructor; you are setting the object's properties to themselves. Additionally I would recommend you use conventions such as classes always start with capital letter, methods other than constructors and variables always start with lower case letter. As it is you have a mixture, sometimes starting with capital, sometimes not, even for the same type of thing.

Comment: Thank you again!! :)